# How to get a Master List from a TPH Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, tph

I am using a Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) Structure for my Code-First Models.
I have a base model Customer:

```
public abstract class Customer : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected BusinessType CustomerType { get; set; }
}
```

I have several Models inherit Customer:

```
public class CommercialCustomer : Customer, IAggregateRoot
{
    public CommercialCustomer()
    {
        CustomerType = BusinessType.Commercial;
    }

    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }        
}


public class ResidentialCustomer : Customer, IAggregateRoot
{
    public ResidentialCustomer()
    {
        CustomerType = BusinessType.Residential;
    }

    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; } 
}


public class EducationalCustomer : Customer, IAggregateRoot
{
    public EducationalCustomer()
    {
        CustomerType = BusinessType.Educational;            
    }

    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; } 
}
```

Etc..
To get a list of Residential Customers I use:

```
   IList<ResidentialCustomer> customers = _context.ResidentialCustomers.ToList();
```

What I need help with is how do I get a Master Customer List as a superset? Calling the .ToList() extension method on Customer just returns the Id property, as expected. Using a SqlDataAdapter I can return a table…

```
const string cmdString =
            "SELECT Id, CONCAT(SchoolName + ', ' + Department, CustomerName, BusinessName) AS Name FROM Customers ORDER BY Name";

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestContext"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdString, connection);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataTable table = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(table);
```

All I really need is just the raw content of the Customers Table from the database to fill a ComboBox. Is there no cleaner way by using only EntityFramework?

Comment: I know that you didn't ask this, but if you're using TPH, consider move to a NoSQL based on documents instead. Basically you'll persist your object exactly how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TPH in code first, the by-the-book way is to only have one DbSet for the whole hierarchy, where the type of the elements is your base type. Then use `.Map` to set up conditions for the derived types on the base entity. When querying for derived types, use the `.OfType<T>()` method on the one entity set to filter by your derived types. The following blurb here shows an example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4